# Problem installing PEAR package with GMP extension requirement

Tags: php, package, pear, gmp

I want to install the Crypt_DiffieHellman PEAR package, that gives me the following error:

```
pear/Crypt_DiffieHellman requires PHP extension "gmp"
```

So I installed the gmp extension (using MacPorts' "php5-gmp"), both `php -m` and `extension_loaded('gmp')` indicate that the extension is loaded. However I still get the PEAR error when I try to install the package.

Am I missing something here? Or is this a (known) bug with the package/PEAR installer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What solved my problem: use the -f (force) argument to ignore missing dependencies. In my case I was sure the extension was installed, so the installer could do without checking this particular extension.